# How to remind a user that it might a good idea to upvote a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, up-votes

In several non-computer-sciences SEs I came across users which have gathered a lot of reputation because they give excellent answers.

I observed that some of them never have upvoted questions even though have answered 1000s.

Personally I upvote questions when I consider the question useful or simply when it is good style, on-topic and/or well written.

How can I encourage a user to upvote a question? How can I politely and context-correctly make sure that this user is aware that questions can be upvoted and that this is actually useful? And if in doubt, how can I initiate a discussion about it with this user?

Comment: Please explain the down-vote.

Comment: The downvotes are likely stating that they disagree with your premise; that you should 'encourage a user to vote in a particular way' whether polite or otherwise. Peoples votes are their own and any suggestions to the contrary tend to be very badly recieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every user has their own style and own way they contribute to the site(s). Some high rep users do a lot of voting and no reviewing. Others do a lot of reviewing and no voting. Some do both and some do neither. And this goes on at lower rep levels as well. As well as asking and/or answering.

What would be the message you would send to other users that don't seem to interact with the community in the same way you do? I don't see this as much of a *real issue*.

Comment: The "issue" is that the people I have in mind are sporadic computer users. And sometimes these kind of people do not obey to system-messages - but they will react to questions/hint asked/given by a human.

Comment: Better late than never: after 2+ years of using SE-sites I only realize now that  the leitmotiv is to be formalized and automatized and depersonalized. Interaction between users apart from asking and answering is not wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The system already reminds you to vote on questions (or answers) if most of your votes have been on answers (or questions). It doesn't tell you which way to vote, but just says something along the lines of:

> You haven't voted on questions for a while, questions need votes too.

Comment: That's if people are only voting on answers, not if they're not voting on anything at all.

Comment: @Servy - True, but there's no indication that the users in question haven't voted on anything.